# How to change the Header HTML of react bootstrap accordion when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a React Bootstrap4 Accordion component that is working 90% correctly.

```jsx
import React, { Component, useState, useContext} from "react";
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion';
import { AccordionContext } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useAccordionToggle } from 'react-bootstrap/AccordionToggle';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'

function Temp() {
  function ContextAwareToggle({ children, eventKey, callback }) {
    const currentEventKey = useContext(AccordionContext);

    const decoratedOnClick = useAccordionToggle(
      eventKey,
      () => callback && callback(eventKey),
    );

    const isCurrentEventKey = currentEventKey === eventKey;

    let toggleText;
    if (isCurrentEventKey) {
      toggleText = '<h3>Up arrow &#5169;</h3>'
    } else {
      toggleText = '<h3>Down arrow &#5167;</h3>'
    }

    return (
      <Accordion.Toggle
        as={Card.Header}
        style={{ backgroundColor: isCurrentEventKey ? '#87CEEB' : '#00BFFF' }}
        onClick={decoratedOnClick}
      >
        {toggleText}
      </Accordion.Toggle>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <h2>Main Heading: </h2> click on the arrow below.
      <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
        <Card>
          <Card.Header>
            <ContextAwareToggle eventKey="0">
            </ContextAwareToggle>
          </Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <Card.Body>
              Accordion Body text
            </Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
      </Accordion>
    </Container>
  )
}
export default Temp;
```

When I click the card.header, the show/hide action is correct. The background color of the header change is correct. However, the text in the header is shown as a literal text. I want the `<h3>` to be interpreted as an HTML tag instead of being displayed in plain text. I also want to show the HTML symbol for the Up and Down arrows instead of the whole `&#5167;` being displayed as plain text.

Comment: You're never using `toggleText`. Are you sure the code in your question is what you're trying to use

Comment: I get the same result even if I replace ```{
      (isCurrentEventKey && <h3>Up arrow &#5169;</h3>) ||
      (!isCurrentEventKey && <h3>Down arrow &#5167;</h3>)
    }``` with ```{toggleText}```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it is a [mcve]. Remove anything not used (like `toggleText`) and clearly describe the result you get vs the result you want

Comment: FYI you might want to use a ternary instead... `{isCurrentEventKey ? <h3>Up arrow &#5169;</h3> : <h3>Down arrow &#5167;</h3>}`

Comment: @Phil : Your comment was the correct answer. Ternary worked instead of toggleText. Now I can see arrows instead of the symbol code and the html tag is interpreted.